# Convert String Token into Tree in Python (Stanford NLP)

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am working on [Stanford NLP](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/stanfordnlp) for one my `Python` project. I want to fetch `word`, `lemma`, `xpos`, `governor` and `dependencies` from it. But the output produced by the API is in String format and like this :

```
<Token index=4;words=[<Word index=4;text=born;lemma=bear;upos=VERB;xpos=VBN;feats=Tense=Past|VerbForm=Part|Voice=Pass;governor=0;dependency_relation=root>]>
<Token index=5;words=[<Word index=5;text=in;lemma=in;upos=ADP;xpos=IN;feats=_;governor=6;dependency_relation=case>]>
<Token index=6;words=[<Word index=6;text=Hawaii;lemma=Hawaii;upos=PROPN;xpos=NNP;feats=Number=Sing;governor=4;dependency_relation=obl>]>
<Token index=7;words=[<Word index=7;text=.;lemma=.;upos=PUNCT;xpos=.;feats=_;governor=4;dependency_relation=punct>]>
```

I want to know how to parse the result to get it into an easy and accessible format. Or Can I convert it into tree form? Or Is there any other library available that gives me lemma, pos tag and dependencies like this?

Comment: If you are looking for other tools, you can check out [spacy](https://spacy.io/) that does dependency parsing. They also offer a way to visualize the parse tree ([displaycy](https://explosion.ai/demos/displacy)).

Comment: Thanks @ygorg ! I tried spacy, it does exactly what I wanted but one feature that is missing is sentence boundary check in spacy, the documentation not clear about its attribute, do you know how to check sentence boundary and parse the given input sentence by sentence?

Comment: In spacy you can get the sentences using `nlp('One sentence. Two sentences.').sents` .

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of research I have found that there is no need to convert this output into tree structure, you can just parse that in `stanford` or the latest `stanza` library by using this:

```
nlp = stanza.Pipeline('en') # This sets up a default neural pipeline in English
doc = nlp("Barack Obama was born in Hawaii.  He was elected president in 2008.")
doc.sentences[0].print_dependencies()

for sent in doc.sentences:
    for word in sent.words:
        print(word.id)
        print(word.text)
        print(word.lemma)
        print(word.xpos)
        print(word.upos)
```

you can easily process the result by this, instead of printing the value you can add you logic.

Also, you can checkout `Spacy` for that, as per @ygorg comment. It has similar feature as `stanford nlp` with dependencies also.

Comment: Yes, you should now be using the Stanza library https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanza/ which has a much better API and can connect well with displaycy through the spacy-stanza interface https://spacy.io/universe/project/spacy-stanza .